# Disable Minimize/Maximize component from RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

This maybe a simple question...I want to disable Minimize/Maximize component from RichTextBox.
I tried to check the properties of RichTextBox, I couldn't succeed to disable these components.

I want to keep the `x` close component but I want to disable Minimize/Maximize component from RichTextBox.

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {          
            ShowRichMessageBox(FileSelected, File.ReadAllText(FileSelected));
        }

 private void ShowRichMessageBox(string title, string message)
        {
            RichTextBox rtbMessage = new RichTextBox();

            rtbMessage.Text = message;          

            Form RichMessageBox = new Form();
            RichMessageBox.Text = title;

            RichMessageBox.Controls.Add(rtbMessage);
            RichMessageBox.ShowDialog();
        }
```

The idea is to display a message in a RichTextBox of the read file.

Comment: do you want to hide minimize button of form??

Comment: @Niranjan Kala: Not the form, to hide minimize button of the `RichTextBox`

Comment: where do you have these button in richtextbox.. standard `RichTextBox` doesn't have any such close or minimize button. what are you using??

Comment: @Niranjan Kala: Updated the button part in the question, thank u.

Comment: Dear it is a `Form` on which you hosted your `RichTextBox`, so you can use the MinimizeBox and MaximizeBox properties of the `Form`. so that i have asked you about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `MinimizeBox` and `MaximizeBox` properties of the `Form`.
Try this:

```
private void ShowRichMessageBox(string title, string message)
        {
            RichTextBox rtbMessage = new RichTextBox();

            rtbMessage.Text = message;          

            Form RichMessageBox = new Form();
            RichMessageBox.Text = title;
            RichMessageBox.MaximizeBox = false;
            RichMessageBox.MinimizeBox = false; 

            RichMessageBox.Controls.Add(rtbMessage);
            RichMessageBox.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Comment: OMG, I tried the same it didn't work before but now...it does. what a stupid i'am...thank u.

Answer (score 0):

RichTextBox control doesn't have Minimize button, only form has it. If you wont to remove form minimize and maximize button add this lines before showing a form :

```
  RichMessageBox.MaximizeBox = false;
  RichMessageBox.MinimizeBox = false;
```